# how to compare two images using SIFT in Linux and Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i need to compare two images. the main purpose is Logo identification. i tried to use SIFT . but i do not understand how to mark key points and comparing. i am using Linux.  I am trying to use SiftDemoV4. can anyone help in using it in Linux command-line step by step. I need to compare two jpg images.

Answer (score 1):

there is a command which let you compare two images. That you can get by installing a package named as `imagemagic`.

open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type as `sudo apt-get install imagemagic`

then do as

```
  compare <Image1.jpeg> <image2.jpeg>  <compare.jpeg>
```

There is a flawless tutorial on Image comparison and I am sure that its gonna help you . http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/

I have tested it my self. look at here

[image]

Comment: hai .. mine is kind of logo identification ... for example.. i have Logo of Dicovey channel.. and i need to compare with other Tv screenshot images. if the logo is identified it should give some output. can i implement such app ??

Comment: @AdityaSukuRaghavit compares those images and will give you what is the difference between those two iamges as the result image. Look at the tutorial link , thats really very good link who needs image comparison.

Comment: i am capturing videos from the televison set top boxes and im cutting into jpg images using ffmpeg. my target is to identify the channel name which currently watching. so i prefered Logo identication and sent the name of the channel to our server. I need to identify the channel Logo . Can u help me in that.?